# Not is possible do event click work through div contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I did a sample chat, but I not understand why not run the links or button interactive on div content.

```js
var ChatCompMap = new Map();

function ChatComponente(c, ident, userimg, username) {

  let id = c + '_' + ident;

  if (!ChatCompMap.has(id))
    ChatCompMap.set(id, {
      chat: c,
      user: ident
    });
  else
    return;

  let chatdiv = document.getElementById(c);

  if (!chatdiv.classList.contains("chat")) {
    /* Requirement componentes */
    var el = document.createElement('style');
    el.innerHTML = '';
    document.head.appendChild(el);

    el = document.createElement('link');
    el.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    el.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
    el.setAttribute("href", "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/englishextra/img-lightbox@latest/img-lightbox.min.css");
    document.head.appendChild(el);

    el = document.createElement('script');
    el.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/englishextra/img-lightbox@latest/img-lightbox.min.js");
    el.onload = function(e) {
      imgLightbox("img-lightbox-link");
    }
    document.head.appendChild(el);

    chatdiv.classList.add("chat");

  }

  let nchatcontainer = document.createElement("div");
  nchatcontainer.setAttribute("id", ident);
  nchatcontainer.setAttribute("class", "chat-container");

  let nchatuserbar = document.createElement("div");
  nchatuserbar.setAttribute("class", "user-bar");

  let nchatconv = document.createElement("div");
  nchatconv.setAttribute("class", "conversation");

  let nchatconvcont = document.createElement("div");
  nchatconvcont.setAttribute("class", "conversation-container");

  let nchatavatar = document.createElement("div");
  nchatavatar.setAttribute("class", "avatar");

  let nchatname = document.createElement("div");
  nchatname.setAttribute("class", "name");

  nchatconv.append(nchatconvcont);

  nchatuserbar.append(nchatavatar);
  nchatuserbar.append(nchatname);

  nchatcontainer.append(nchatuserbar);
  nchatcontainer.append(nchatconv);

  chatdiv.append(nchatcontainer);

  let url = null;

  if (!userimg)
    userimg = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==";

  url = userimg;

  if (!username)
    username = "Usuário #" + ChatCompMap.size.toString();

  let img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = url;

  let slct = '#' + c + ' > #' + ident + ' > div.user-bar > div.avatar';
  let slctn = '#' + c + ' > #' + ident + ' > div.user-bar > div.name';

  let obj = document.querySelector(slct);
  obj.append(img);

  obj = document.querySelector(slctn);
  obj.innerHTML = username;

}

function buildMessage(text, mode, h, file, mime) {
  var element = document.createElement('div');

  element.classList.add('message', mode);

  //test onclick
  //element.setAttribute("onclick","alert(\'GGG\');");

  var content = "";

  if (mime === "image") {
    content = '<a href="' + file + '" class="img-lightbox-link" aria-hidden="true">' +
      '<div class="message-image" onclick="alert(\'tst\');">' +
      '<img src="' + file + '" style="margin: -50% -40%;"></div></a><a href="http://uol.com.br">Teste</a>';
  }

  if (mime === "video") {
    content = '<video controls width="320" height="240" class="message-video"><source src="' + file + '" type="video/mp4">' +
      'Your browser does not support the video tag.</video><br>';
  }

  if (mime === "audio") {

    /*var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', file, true);
    request.responseType = 'blob';
    request.withCredentials = false;
    request.onload = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
        reader.onload =  function(e){
            console.log('DataURL:', e.target.result);
        };
    };
    request.send();*/

    content = '<audio controls autobuffer class="message-audio">' +
      '<source src="' + file + '" >' +
      'Your browser does not support the video tag.</audio><br>';
  }

  if (mime === "location") {
    content = '<button class="message-btn" nclick="window.open(\'' + file + '\', \'_blank\');"><svg width="50" height="50" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="map-marked-alt" class="svg-inline--fa fa-map-marked-alt fa-w-18" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M288 0c-69.59 0-126 56.41-126 126 0 56.26 82.35 158.8 113.9 196.02 6.39 7.54 17.82 7.54 24.2 0C331.65 284.8 414 182.26 414 126 414 56.41 357.59 0 288 0zm0 168c-23.2 0-42-18.8-42-42s18.8-42 42-42 42 18.8 42 42-18.8 42-42 42zM20.12 215.95A32.006 32.006 0 0 0 0 245.66v250.32c0 11.32 11.43 19.06 21.94 14.86L160 448V214.92c-8.84-15.98-16.07-31.54-21.25-46.42L20.12 215.95zM288 359.67c-14.07 0-27.38-6.18-36.51-16.96-19.66-23.2-40.57-49.62-59.49-76.72v182l192 64V266c-18.92 27.09-39.82 53.52-59.49 76.72-9.13 10.77-22.44 16.95-36.51 16.95zm266.06-198.51L416 224v288l139.88-55.95A31.996 31.996 0 0 0 576 426.34V176.02c0-11.32-11.43-19.06-21.94-14.86z"></path></svg></br>Goole Maps</button>';
  }

  if (mime === "document") {
    content = '<button class="message-btn" nclick="window.open(\'' + file + '\', \'_blank\');"><svg width="50" height="50" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="file-download" class="svg-inline--fa fa-file-download fa-w-12" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M224 136V0H24C10.7 0 0 10.7 0 24v464c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h336c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V160H248c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24zm76.45 211.36l-96.42 95.7c-6.65 6.61-17.39 6.61-24.04 0l-96.42-95.7C73.42 337.29 80.54 320 94.82 320H160v-80c0-8.84 7.16-16 16-16h32c8.84 0 16 7.16 16 16v80h65.18c14.28 0 21.4 17.29 11.27 27.36zM377 105L279.1 7c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H256v128h128v-6.1c0-6.3-2.5-12.4-7-16.9z"></path></svg></br>Download</button>';
  }

  element.innerHTML = content + text +
    '<span class="metadata">' +
    '<span class="time">' + h + '</span>' +
    '<span class="tick tick-animation">' +
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="15" id="msg-dblcheck" x="2047" y="2061"><path d="M15.01 3.316l-.478-.372a.365.365 0 0 0-.51.063L8.666 9.88a.32.32 0 0 1-.484.032l-.358-.325a.32.32 0 0 0-.484.032l-.378.48a.418.418 0 0 0 .036.54l1.32 1.267a.32.32 0 0 0 .484-.034l6.272-8.048a.366.366 0 0 0-.064-.512zm-4.1 0l-.478-.372a.365.365 0 0 0-.51.063L4.566 9.88a.32.32 0 0 1-.484.032L1.892 7.77a.366.366 0 0 0-.516.005l-.423.433a.364.364 0 0 0 .006.514l3.255 3.185a.32.32 0 0 0 .484-.033l6.272-8.048a.365.365 0 0 0-.063-.51z" fill="#92a58c"/></svg>' +
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="15" id="msg-dblcheck-ack" x="2063" y="2076"><path d="M15.01 3.316l-.478-.372a.365.365 0 0 0-.51.063L8.666 9.88a.32.32 0 0 1-.484.032l-.358-.325a.32.32 0 0 0-.484.032l-.378.48a.418.418 0 0 0 .036.54l1.32 1.267a.32.32 0 0 0 .484-.034l6.272-8.048a.366.366 0 0 0-.064-.512zm-4.1 0l-.478-.372a.365.365 0 0 0-.51.063L4.566 9.88a.32.32 0 0 1-.484.032L1.892 7.77a.366.366 0 0 0-.516.005l-.423.433a.364.364 0 0 0 .006.514l3.255 3.185a.32.32 0 0 0 .484-.033l6.272-8.048a.365.365 0 0 0-.063-.51z" fill="#4fc3f7"/></svg>' +
    '</span>' +
    '</span>';

  return element;
}

function animateMessage(message) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var tick = message.querySelector('.tick');
    tick.classList.remove('tick-animation');
  }, 500);
}

/* ------- novas funcoes ------------- */

function ChatComponentExist(c, ident) {
  let id = c + '_' + ident;
  return ChatCompMap.has(id);
}

function ChatNewMessage(c, ident, e, s, h, file, mime) {

  let id = c + '_' + ident;

  if (!ChatCompMap.has(id))
    return;

  var conversation = document.querySelector('#' + c + ' > #' + ident + ' > div.conversation > div.conversation-container');
  var input = e; //e.target.input;

  if (input || file) {
    var message = buildMessage(input, s, h, file, mime);
    conversation.appendChild(message);
    animateMessage(message);
  }

  conversation.scrollTop = conversation.scrollHeight;
}


function ChatComponentClear(c, ident) {

  let id = c + '_' + ident;

  if (!ChatCompMap.has(id))
    return;

  const myNode = document.querySelector('#' + c + '> #' + ident);
  while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.lastChild);
  }
  myNode.remove();

  ChatCompMap.delete(id);
}

function ChatComponentShow(c, ident, shw) {

  let id = c + '_' + ident;

  if (!ChatCompMap.has(id))
    return;

  const myNode = document.querySelector('#' + c + '> #' + ident);

  if (!shw) {
    if (!myNode.classList.contains("ChatConvHid"))
      myNode.classList.add("ChatConvHid");
  } else {
    if (!myNode.classList.contains("ChatConvHid"))
      myNode.classList.remove("ChatConvHid");
  }
}

ChatComponente("chat", "paulo", avatar, "Paulo Corcino");
ChatNewMessage("chat", "paulo", "Exemplo Texto", "sent", "8:00", null, null);
ChatNewMessage("chat", "paulo", "Exemplo Texto Recebido", "received", "8:01", null, null);
ChatNewMessage("chat", "paulo", "Exemplo Imagem", "received", "8:01", nphoto, "image");
ChatNewMessage("chat", "paulo", "", "sent", "8:01", avatar, "image");
ChatNewMessage("chat", "paulo", "Exemplo Video", "received", "8:01", nvideo, "video");
ChatNewMessage("chat", "paulo", "Exemplo Audio", "received", "8:01", naudio, "audio");
ChatNewMessage("chat", "paulo", "Exemplo Documento", "received", "8:01", ndocument, "document");
ChatNewMessage("chat", "paulo", "Exemplo Localização", "received", "8:01", latlon, "location");

ChatComponentShow("chat", "paulo", true);
//http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-10.9498287,-37.0654272&z18
//@-10.9498287,-37.0654272&z=
```

```css
html {
  /* box-sizing: border-box;*/
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /*-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.chat {
  height: calc(100% - 48px);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.chat-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.user-bar {
  height: 55px;
  background: #005e54;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.user-bar:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.user-bar div {
  float: left;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}

.user-bar .actions {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.user-bar .actions.more {
  margin: 0 12px 0 32px;
}

.user-bar .actions.attachment {
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.user-bar .actions.attachment i {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.user-bar .avatar {
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
}

.user-bar .avatar img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.user-bar .name {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 80%;
}

.user-bar .status {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

.conversation {
  height: calc(100% - 12px);
  position: relative;
  background: #efe7dd url("https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/398893/15136779/4e765036-1639-11e6-9201-67e728e86f39.jpg") repeat;
  z-index: 0;
}

.conversation ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  transition: all .5s;
  width: 5px;
  height: 1px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.conversation ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

.conversation ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #b3ada7;
}

.conversation .conversation-container {
  /*height: calc(100% - 68px);*/
  height: 100%;
  /*box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -10px #000000;*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0 16px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.conversation .conversation-container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.message {
  color: #000;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 18px;
  /*font-size: 15px;*/
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  max-width: 85%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  z-index: -1;
}

.message:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

.metadata {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 0 7px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -4px;
}

.metadata .time {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.metadata .tick {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}

.metadata .tick svg {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.metadata .tick svg:first-child {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.metadata .tick svg:last-child {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.metadata .tick-animation svg:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
}

.metadata .tick-animation svg:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(-179.9deg);
}

.message:first-child {
  margin: 16px 0 8px;
}

.message.received {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  float: left;
}

.message.received .metadata {
  padding: 0 0 0 16px;
}

.message.received:after {
  border-width: 0px 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
}

.message.sent {
  background: #e1ffc7;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  float: right;
}

.message.sent:after {
  border-width: 0px 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #e1ffc7;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
}

.ChatConvHid {
  display: none !important;
}

.message-video {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.message-image {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.message-audio {}

.message-document {}

.message-location {}

.message-btn {
  background-color: #b3ada7;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif !important;
}

.message-btn:hover {
  background-color: #86817c;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .marvel-device.nexus5 {
    border-radius: 0;
    flex: none;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .marvel-device>.screen .chat {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .marvel-device {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .marvel-device .status-bar {
    display: none;
  }
  .screen-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .conversation {
    height: calc(100vh - 55px);
  }
  .conversation .conversation-container {
    height: calc(100vh - 120px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Chat</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var avatar = "http://sistemas.corcino.com.br:8020/somos/getfile.rule?sys=BOT&arquivo=userimage@1@4@7FD66E9B1F9F486D8C95";
    var nphoto = "http://sistemas.corcino.com.br:8020/somos/getfile.rule?sys=BOT&arquivo=dataimage_jpeg@1@4@C661281C60B847759EEB";
    var nvideo = "http://sistemas.corcino.com.br:8020/somos/getfile.rule?sys=BOT&arquivo=datavideo_mp4@1@4@4F5D6E742634422DAF2B";
    var nlocation = "location@1@4@314123992DA4406CAA7F";
    var ndocument = "http://sistemas.corcino.com.br:8020/somos/getfile.rule?sys=BOT&arquivo=04contrachequeintranetperbras_pdf@1@4@7168A9C3138745E99F3C";
    var naudio = "http://sistemas.corcino.com.br:8020/somos/getfile.rule?sys=BOT&arquivo=dataaudio_ogg@1@4@16CC8FAD9C8A469A8125";
    var latlon = "-10.9498287,-37.0654272";
  </script>


  <div id="chat"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just to review your stylesheet rules, remove or review accordingly your z-indexes, z-index to -1 make your divs unclickable if there are elements with greater z-index, then there are some typos in the onclick handlers in the markup, it should be onclick and not nclick.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Chat</title>
    <style>
        
html {
 /* box-sizing: border-box;*/
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /*-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.chat {
    height: calc(100% - 48px);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.chat-container {
    height: 100%;
}

.user-bar {
    height: 55px;
    background: #005e54;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 8px;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: relative;
    /* z-index: 1; */
}

.user-bar:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.user-bar div {
    float: left;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}

.user-bar .actions {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.user-bar .actions.more {
    margin: 0 12px 0 32px;
}

.user-bar .actions.attachment {
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.user-bar .actions.attachment i {
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.user-bar .avatar {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
}

.user-bar .avatar img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.user-bar .name {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    margin: 0 0 0 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 80%;
}

.user-bar .status {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

.conversation {
    height: calc(100% - 12px);
    position: relative;
    background: #efe7dd url("https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/398893/15136779/4e765036-1639-11e6-9201-67e728e86f39.jpg") repeat;
    z-index: 0;
}

.conversation ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    /* transition: all .5s;
    width: 5px;
    height: 1px;
    z-index: 10; */
}

.conversation ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    /* background: transparent; */
}

.conversation ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #b3ada7;
}

.conversation .conversation-container {
    /*height: calc(100% - 68px);*/
    height: 100%;
    /*box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -10px #000000;*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0 16px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.conversation .conversation-container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.message {
    color: #000;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 18px;
    /*font-size: 15px;*/
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 8px 0;
    max-width: 85%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /* z-index: -1; */
}

.message:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

.metadata {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 0 0 7px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -4px;
}

.metadata .time {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.metadata .tick {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2px;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}

.metadata .tick svg {
    position: absolute;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.metadata .tick svg:first-child {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.metadata .tick svg:last-child {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.metadata .tick-animation svg:first-child {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
}

.metadata .tick-animation svg:last-child {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(-179.9deg);
}

.message:first-child {
    margin: 16px 0 8px;
}

.message.received {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    float: left;
}

.message.received .metadata {
    padding: 0 0 0 16px;
}

.message.received:after {
    border-width: 0px 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
    top: 0;
    left: -10px;
}

.message.sent {
    background: #e1ffc7;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    float: right;
}

.message.sent:after {
    border-width: 0px 0 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #e1ffc7;
    top: 0;
    right: -10px;
}

.ChatConvHid {
    display: none !important;
}

.message-video {
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.message-image {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.message-audio {

}

.message-document {

}

.message-location {

}

.message-btn {
  background-color: #b3ada7;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif !important;
}

.message-btn:hover {
  background-color: #86817c;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .marvel-device.nexus5 {
        border-radius: 0;
        flex: none;
        padding: 0;
        max-width: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .marvel-device>.screen .chat {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .marvel-device {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .marvel-device .status-bar {
        display: none;
    }
    .screen-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    .conversation {
        height: calc(100vh - 55px);
    }
    .conversation .conversation-container {
        height: calc(100vh - 120px);
    }
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      var avatar =
        "http://sistemas.corcino.com.br:8020/somos/getfile.rule?sys=BOT&arquivo=userimage@1@4@7FD66E9B1F9F486D8C95";
      var nphoto =
        "http://sistemas.corcino.com.br:8020/somos/getfile.rule?sys=BOT&arquivo=dataimage_jpeg@1@4@C661281C60B847759EEB";
      var nvideo =
        "http://sistemas.corcino.com.br:8020/somos/getfile.rule?sys=BOT&arquivo=datavideo_mp4@1@4@4F5D6E742634422DAF2B";
      var nlocation = "location@1@4@314123992DA4406CAA7F";
      var ndocument =
        "http://sistemas.corcino.com.br:8020/somos/getfile.rule?sys=BOT&arquivo=04contrachequeintranetperbras_pdf@1@4@7168A9C3138745E99F3C";
      var naudio =
        "http://sistemas.corcino.com.br:8020/somos/getfile.rule?sys=BOT&arquivo=dataaudio_ogg@1@4@16CC8FAD9C8A469A8125";
      var latlon = "-10.9498287,-37.0654272";
    </script>

    <div id="chat"></div>
    <script>
      var ChatCompMap = new Map();

      function ChatComponente(c, ident, userimg, username) {
        let id = c + "_" + ident;

        if (!ChatCompMap.has(id)) ChatCompMap.set(id, { chat: c, user: ident });
        else return;

        let chatdiv = document.getElementById(c);

        if (!chatdiv.classList.contains("chat")) {
          /* Requirement componentes */
          var el = document.createElement("style");
          el.innerHTML = "";
          document.head.appendChild(el);

          el = document.createElement("link");
          el.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
          el.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
          el.setAttribute(
            "href",
            "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/englishextra/img-lightbox@latest/img-lightbox.min.css"
          );
          document.head.appendChild(el);

          el = document.createElement("script");
          el.setAttribute(
            "src",
            "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/englishextra/img-lightbox@latest/img-lightbox.min.js"
          );
          el.onload = function (e) {
            imgLightbox("img-lightbox-link");
          };
          document.head.appendChild(el);

          chatdiv.classList.add("chat");
        }

        let nchatcontainer = document.createElement("div");
        nchatcontainer.setAttribute("id", ident);
        nchatcontainer.setAttribute("class", "chat-container");

        let nchatuserbar = document.createElement("div");
        nchatuserbar.setAttribute("class", "user-bar");

        let nchatconv = document.createElement("div");
        nchatconv.setAttribute("class", "conversation");

        let nchatconvcont = document.createElement("div");
        nchatconvcont.setAttribute("class", "conversation-container");

        let nchatavatar = document.createElement("div");
        nchatavatar.setAttribute("class", "avatar");

        let nchatname = document.createElement("div");
        nchatname.setAttribute("class", "name");

        nchatconv.append(nchatconvcont);

        nchatuserbar.append(nchatavatar);
        nchatuserbar.append(nchatname);

        nchatcontainer.append(nchatuserbar);
        nchatcontainer.append(nchatconv);

        chatdiv.append(nchatcontainer);

        let url = null;

        if (!userimg)
          userimg =
            "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==";

        url = userimg;

        if (!username) username = "Usuário #" + ChatCompMap.size.toString();

        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = url;

        let slct = "#" + c + " > #" + ident + " > div.user-bar > div.avatar";
        let slctn = "#" + c + " > #" + ident + " > div.user-bar > div.name";

        let obj = document.querySelector(slct);
        obj.append(img);

        obj = document.querySelector(slctn);
        obj.innerHTML = username;
      }

      function buildMessage(text, mode, h, file, mime) {
        var element = document.createElement("div");

        element.classList.add("message", mode);

        //test onclick
        //element.setAttribute("onclick","alert(\'GGG\');");

        var content = "";

        if (mime === "image") {
          content =
            '<a href="' +
            file +
            '" class="img-lightbox-link" aria-hidden="true">' +
            '<div class="message-image" onclick="alert(\'tst\');">' +
            '<img src="' +
            file +
            '" style="margin: -50% -40%;"></div></a><a href="http://uol.com.br">Teste</a>';
        }

        if (mime === "video") {
          content =
            '<video controls width="320" height="240" class="message-video"><source src="' +
            file +
            '" type="video/mp4">' +
            "Your browser does not support the video tag.</video><br>";
        }

        if (mime === "audio") {
          /*var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', file, true);
        request.responseType = 'blob';
        request.withCredentials = false;
        request.onload = function() {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
            reader.onload =  function(e){
                console.log('DataURL:', e.target.result);
            };
        };
        request.send();*/

          content =
            '<audio controls autobuffer class="message-audio">' +
            '<source src="' +
            file +
            '" >' +
            "Your browser does not support the video tag.</audio><br>";
        }

        if (mime === "location") {
          content =
            '<button class="message-btn" onclick="window.open(\'' +
            file +
            '\', \'_blank\');"><svg width="50" height="50" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="map-marked-alt" class="svg-inline--fa fa-map-marked-alt fa-w-18" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M288 0c-69.59 0-126 56.41-126 126 0 56.26 82.35 158.8 113.9 196.02 6.39 7.54 17.82 7.54 24.2 0C331.65 284.8 414 182.26 414 126 414 56.41 357.59 0 288 0zm0 168c-23.2 0-42-18.8-42-42s18.8-42 42-42 42 18.8 42 42-18.8 42-42 42zM20.12 215.95A32.006 32.006 0 0 0 0 245.66v250.32c0 11.32 11.43 19.06 21.94 14.86L160 448V214.92c-8.84-15.98-16.07-31.54-21.25-46.42L20.12 215.95zM288 359.67c-14.07 0-27.38-6.18-36.51-16.96-19.66-23.2-40.57-49.62-59.49-76.72v182l192 64V266c-18.92 27.09-39.82 53.52-59.49 76.72-9.13 10.77-22.44 16.95-36.51 16.95zm266.06-198.51L416 224v288l139.88-55.95A31.996 31.996 0 0 0 576 426.34V176.02c0-11.32-11.43-19.06-21.94-14.86z"></path></svg></br>Goole Maps</button>';
        }

        if (mime === "document") {
          content =
            '<button class="message-btn" onclick="window.open(\'' +
            file +
            '\', \'_blank\');"><svg width="50" height="50" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="file-download" class="svg-inline--fa fa-file-download fa-w-12" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M224 136V0H24C10.7 0 0 10.7 0 24v464c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24h336c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24V160H248c-13.2 0-24-10.8-24-24zm76.45 211.36l-96.42 95.7c-6.65 6.61-17.39 6.61-24.04 0l-96.42-95.7C73.42 337.29 80.54 320 94.82 320H160v-80c0-8.84 7.16-16 16-16h32c8.84 0 16 7.16 16 16v80h65.18c14.28 0 21.4 17.29 11.27 27.36zM377 105L279.1 7c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H256v128h128v-6.1c0-6.3-2.5-12.4-7-16.9z"></path></svg></br>Download</button>';
        }

        element.innerHTML =
          content +
          text +
          '<span class="metadata">' +
          '<span class="time">' +
          h +
          "</span>" +
          '<span class="tick tick-animation">' +
          '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="15" id="msg-dblcheck" x="2047" y="2061"><path d="M15.01 3.316l-.478-.372a.365.365 0 0 0-.51.063L8.666 9.88a.32.32 0 0 1-.484.032l-.358-.325a.32.32 0 0 0-.484.032l-.378.48a.418.418 0 0 0 .036.54l1.32 1.267a.32.32 0 0 0 .484-.034l6.272-8.048a.366.366 0 0 0-.064-.512zm-4.1 0l-.478-.372a.365.365 0 0 0-.51.063L4.566 9.88a.32.32 0 0 1-.484.032L1.892 7.77a.366.366 0 0 0-.516.005l-.423.433a.364.364 0 0 0 .006.514l3.255 3.185a.32.32 0 0 0 .484-.033l6.272-8.048a.365.365 0 0 0-.063-.51z" fill="#92a58c"/></svg>' +
          '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="15" id="msg-dblcheck-ack" x="2063" y="2076"><path d="M15.01 3.316l-.478-.372a.365.365 0 0 0-.51.063L8.666 9.88a.32.32 0 0 1-.484.032l-.358-.325a.32.32 0 0 0-.484.032l-.378.48a.418.418 0 0 0 .036.54l1.32 1.267a.32.32 0 0 0 .484-.034l6.272-8.048a.366.366 0 0 0-.064-.512zm-4.1 0l-.478-.372a.365.365 0 0 0-.51.063L4.566 9.88a.32.32 0 0 1-.484.032L1.892 7.77a.366.366 0 0 0-.516.005l-.423.433a.364.364 0 0 0 .006.514l3.255 3.185a.32.32 0 0 0 .484-.033l6.272-8.048a.365.365 0 0 0-.063-.51z" fill="#4fc3f7"/></svg>' +
          "</span>" +
          "</span>";

        return element;
      }

      function animateMessage(message) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          var tick = message.querySelector(".tick");
          tick.classList.remove("tick-animation");
        }, 500);
      }

      /* ------- novas funcoes ------------- */

      function ChatComponentExist(c, ident) {
        let id = c + "_" + ident;
        return ChatCompMap.has(id);
      }

      function ChatNewMessage(c, ident, e, s, h, file, mime) {
        let id = c + "_" + ident;

        if (!ChatCompMap.has(id)) return;

        var conversation = document.querySelector(
          "#" +
            c +
            " > #" +
            ident +
            " > div.conversation > div.conversation-container"
        );
        var input = e; //e.target.input;

        if (input || file) {
          var message = buildMessage(input, s, h, file, mime);
          conversation.appendChild(message);
          animateMessage(message);
        }

        conversation.scrollTop = conversation.scrollHeight;
      }

      function ChatComponentClear(c, ident) {
        let id = c + "_" + ident;

        if (!ChatCompMap.has(id)) return;

        const myNode = document.querySelector("#" + c + "> #" + ident);
        while (myNode.firstChild) {
          myNode.removeChild(myNode.lastChild);
        }
        myNode.remove();

        ChatCompMap.delete(id);
      }

      function ChatComponentShow(c, ident, shw) {
        let id = c + "_" + ident;

        if (!ChatCompMap.has(id)) return;

        const myNode = document.querySelector("#" + c + "> #" + ident);

        if (!shw) {
          if (!myNode.classList.contains("ChatConvHid"))
            myNode.classList.add("ChatConvHid");
        } else {
          if (!myNode.classList.contains("ChatConvHid"))
            myNode.classList.remove("ChatConvHid");
        }
      }

      ChatComponente("chat", "paulo", avatar, "Paulo Corcino");
      ChatNewMessage(
        "chat",
        "paulo",
        "Exemplo Texto",
        "sent",
        "8:00",
        null,
        null
      );
      ChatNewMessage(
        "chat",
        "paulo",
        "Exemplo Texto Recebido",
        "received",
        "8:01",
        null,
        null
      );
      ChatNewMessage(
        "chat",
        "paulo",
        "Exemplo Imagem",
        "received",
        "8:01",
        nphoto,
        "image"
      );
      ChatNewMessage("chat", "paulo", "", "sent", "8:01", avatar, "image");
      ChatNewMessage(
        "chat",
        "paulo",
        "Exemplo Video",
        "received",
        "8:01",
        nvideo,
        "video"
      );
      ChatNewMessage(
        "chat",
        "paulo",
        "Exemplo Audio",
        "received",
        "8:01",
        naudio,
        "audio"
      );
      ChatNewMessage(
        "chat",
        "paulo",
        "Exemplo Documento",
        "received",
        "8:01",
        ndocument,
        "document"
      );
      ChatNewMessage(
        "chat",
        "paulo",
        "Exemplo Localização",
        "received",
        "8:01",
        latlon,
        "location"
      );

      ChatComponentShow("chat", "paulo", true);
      //http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-10.9498287,-37.0654272&z18
      //@-10.9498287,-37.0654272&z=
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

all the best